# Arranging a Dataframe to a specific format using a loop in Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, jupyter-notebook

I'm a python noob. I have the following data frame which needs to be arranged as the example output below. Please note this is a simplified version of the Data frame and the data continues for 3 months. Source file is an unstructured txt file.

Dataframe

|  | 0 | 36 | 43 | 79 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | TDY | 1.2 | TOM | 1.2 |
| 2 | SPT | 1.4 | 1WK | 1.4 |
| 3 | 2WK | 1.5 | 1MO | 1.6 |
| 4 | 2MO | 1.7 | 3MO | 1.7 |
| 5 | 6MO | 1.4 | 9MO | 1.8 |
| 6 | 1YR | 1.7 | 2YR | 1.3 |
| 7 | 3YR | 1.2 | 4YR | 1.2 |
| 8 | 5YR | 1.4 | 6YR | 1.4 |
| 9 | TDY | 1.2 | TOM | 1.2 |
| 10 | SPT | 1.4 | 1WK | 1.4 |
| 11 | 2WK | 1.5 | 1MO | 1.6 |
| 12 | 2MO | 1.7 | 3MO | 1.7 |
| 13 | 6MO | 1.4 | 9MO | 1.8 |
| 14 | 1YR | 1.7 | 2YR | 1.3 |
| 15 | 3YR | 1.2 | 4YR | 1.2 |
| 16 | 5YR | 1.4 | 6YR | 1.4 |
| 17 | TDY | 1.2 | TOM | 1.2 |
| 18 | SPT | 1.4 | 1WK | 1.4 |
| 19 | 2WK | 1.5 | 1MO | 1.6 |
| 20 | 2MO | 1.7 | 3MO | 1.7 |
| 21 | 6MO | 1.4 | 9MO | 1.8 |
| 22 | 1YR | 1.7 | 2YR | 1.3 |
| 23 | 3YR | 1.2 | 4YR | 1.2 |
| 24 | 5YR | 1.4 | 6YR | 1.4 |

Output required

| TDY | TOM | SPT | 1WK | 2WK | 1MO | 2MO | 3MO | 6MO | 9MO | 1YR | 2YR | 3YR | 4YR | 5YR | 6YR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.2 | 1.2 | 1.4 | 1.4 | 1.5 | 1.6 | 1.7 | 1.7 | 1.4 | 1.8 | 1.7 | 1.3 | 1.2 | 1.2 | 1.4 | 1.4 |
| 1.2 | 1.2 | 1.4 | 1.4 | 1.5 | 1.6 | 1.7 | 1.7 | 1.4 | 1.8 | 1.7 | 1.3 | 1.2 | 1.2 | 1.4 | 1.4 |
| 1.2 | 1.2 | 1.4 | 1.4 | 1.5 | 1.6 | 1.7 | 1.7 | 1.4 | 1.8 | 1.7 | 1.3 | 1.2 | 1.2 | 1.4 | 1.4 |

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3O0R3.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [pd.melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html)

```
column_order = ["TDY", "TOM", "SPT", "1WK", "2WK", "1MO", "2MO", "3MO",
                "6MO", "9MO", "1YR", "2YR", "3YR", "4YR", "5YR", "6YR"]

header_df = df[["0", "43"]].melt(value_name="headers")
value_df = df[["36", "79"]].melt(value_name="values")
melted_df = pd.concat([header_df, value_df], axis=1)[["headers", "values"]]

grouped_mapping = melted_df.groupby("headers")["values"].apply(list).to_dict()
final_df = pd.DataFrame(grouped_mapping).reindex(columns=column_order)
print(final_df)

   TDY  TOM  SPT  1WK  2WK  1MO  2MO  3MO  6MO  9MO  1YR  2YR  3YR  4YR  5YR  6YR
0  1.2  1.2  1.4  1.4  1.5  1.6  1.7  1.7  1.4  1.8  1.7  1.3  1.2  1.2  1.4  1.4
1  1.2  1.2  1.4  1.4  1.5  1.6  1.7  1.7  1.4  1.8  1.7  1.3  1.2  1.2  1.4  1.4
2  1.2  1.2  1.4  1.4  1.5  1.6  1.7  1.7  1.4  1.8  1.7  1.3  1.2  1.2  1.4  1.4
```

Comment: Hi jason. Thank you so much. However my output came differently. I have attached the image on the bottom of the question. Let me know if you have any clarifications.

Comment: Seems like some of the data has gone missing too.

Comment: Ok I think the edit is what you wanted? It loses the column  order is that a big deal?

Comment: Hi. yes the order has to be the same way. is that possible?

Comment: Ok fixed the column order